# Failed to fetch data from firebase in Php

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my error that is showing after click on accounts Button plz help me into this i am new to programing any help will   be appreciated plz help me into this i had also attached image of firebase database the database is aslso set to open for write and read to public:

[image]

```
 Read.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database(...).ref(...).then is not a function
at getdata (VM1188 Read.js:2)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):8)
 getdata @ Read.js:2
 onclick @ (index):8
```

function getdata() {

```
   const db = firebase.database().ref('test1-8c715-default-rtdb');
    db.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {


    var Name=snapshot.val().Name;
    var Email=snapshot.val().Email;
    var contactno=snapshot.val().phoneno;

   

    document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML=Name;
    document.getElementById("Email").innerHTML=Email;
    document.getElementById("phoneno").innerHTML=phoneno;
})
```

}

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Accounts</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Read.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <button type="button"  onclick="getdata()">Accounts</button>
    <!-- <button type="button" onclick="getdata();">Account</button> -->
</center>
<center>
    <p>Email: <strong id="Email"></strong></p>
    <p>Contactno: <strong id="phoneno"></strong></p>
    <p>Name: <strong id="Name"></strong></p>
</center>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ".............",
    authDomain: "test1-8c715.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test1-8c715-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test1-8c715",
    storageBucket: "test1-8c715.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "401523276961",
    appId: "1:401523276961:web:fc53ded09831fbc7690...4e0",
    measurementId: "G-PS.....5KQT2"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Read.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Never post personal info or critical info like api-keys, replace with dots or so.

Comment: @Grumpy Those keys are not a secret in the case of Firebase. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public/37484053#37484053

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this line:

```
const db = firebase.database().ref('test1-8c715-default-rtdb').then(function (snapshot) {
```

The first part should be:

```
const db = firebase.database('your-full-database-url').ref();
```

In addition this is a synchronous operation, so it doesn't return a promise that you call `then()` on. Instead this merely sets up a reference to the database.

To then read data from the database, use once()`or`get()`:

```
db.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

---

I think you'll need to include the full URL in that `ref('test1-8c715-default-rtdb')`, so be sure to copy it from the database panel in the Firebase console of your project. And finally, you'll need to pass that URL to the `database` call and not to `ref()`.

Comment: still same Eror

Comment: That seems unexpected. Can you edit your question to show the updated code?

Comment: Ah yeah, I now see the additional problem: you need to pass the *full* database URL into the `database()` function, not into `ref()`. See the update in my answer.